# Scala: Variable Reference

Tags: scala, reference

How in Scala can you reference a variable to another? E.g.

```
import scala.collection.mutable.Set
var a = Set(1)
var b = a
a = a + 2
// a = Set(1, 2)
// b = Set(1)
```

I'd want `b` to point to the "updated" `a`.

Comment: @MikeAllen You didn't?

Answer (score 4):

Let's see what's going on:

```
scala> var a = Set(1)
a: scala.collection.mutable.Set[Int] = Set(1)

scala> var b = a
b: scala.collection.mutable.Set[Int] = Set(1)

scala> a eq b
res9: Boolean = true
```

That means the two variables reference the same value (in this case, mutable reference because you used `var`).

Now let's see what happens if we do `a = a + 2`:

```
scala> a = a + 2
a: scala.collection.mutable.Set[Int] = Set(1, 2)

scala> a eq b
res10: Boolean = false
```

What we should use is the `+=` operator which, in the case of `a += 2`, will be desugared by the compiler as `a.+=(2)` (the operation `+=` from `Set`) maintaining the reference of `a` and making the change in place. If you do `a = a + 2` instead you are changing the object referenced by `a` to a new one `a + 2` and hence changing the hashcode. And, as the data structure you are using is mutable, you can change the mutable references by immutable ones using `val`s.

Comment: Beautiful. I love it that the haschodes are actual hashes, and I get the same ones. +1

Comment: @MikeAllen Unlikely? `1453501670` seems pretty preimage resistant.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `def` instead of `var` like this

```
def b = a
```

then accessing `b` will always return the latest value of `a`. But it is better to use `val` and update the `Set` in-place as explained in other answers to your question.

Better still, consider how you might use a more functional style and avoid having values that change over time like this.